# how to timer inside loop?

Tags: c#, timer

I want to send alert for today at different time interval. I wrote the code as follows, but it never calls the method `SendAlert()`. Where do I go wrong?

```
//AletForToday gives me at what time i need to send alert.
for (int i = 0; i < AlertForToday.Count();i++)
{
    TimeSpan day = new TimeSpan(24, 00, 00);    // 24 hours in a day.
    TimeSpan now = TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("HH:mm"));  
    TimeSpan activationTime = TimeSpan.Parse(AlertForToday.dt.ToString("HH:mm"));   // 11:45 pm              
    TimeSpan timeLeftUntilFirstRun = ((day - now) + activationTime);
    if (timeLeftUntilFirstRun.TotalHours > 24)
    timeLeftUntilFirstRun -= new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
    System.Timers.Timer timers = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timers.Interval = timeLeftUntilFirstRun.TotalMilliseconds;
    timers.AutoReset = false;
    timers.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {                        
        SendAlert(AlertForToday[i]);
    });
    timers.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing over the loop variable `i`.  Closures close over variables, not values, so the timer's event is using the value of `i` when it fires, not when you added the handler.  At that point in time the value of `i` is after the end of the collection, so the event is only ever throwing an index out of range exception.

Create a copy of `i` inside the body of the `for` loop and close over that copy.

That, or use a `foreach` loop to iterate `AlertForToday` rather than a `for` loop, because the loop variable of a `foreach` is re-created on each iteration, rather than re-using the same variable like a `for` loop.